# Using the Method of Undetermined Coefficients

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation

I have been given a question that reads:

> Use the method of undetermined coefficients to find an approximation for the second derivative of the form:
> $$f''(0) \approx A f(-h) + B f(0) + C f(h),$$ which is exact for all quadratic polynomials.

To be perfectly honest, I have no idea how to commence this question, nor the purpose of it, nor how it works. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: The "undetermined coefficients" here are $A,B,C$, so don't be too put off by that phrase.  Instead you should replace $f$ by some quadratic polynomials and use the resulting (linear) equations in $A,B,C$ to determine what those coefficients need to be.  (NB: If the coefficients work for two quadratic polynomials $p,q$, then the will also work for any linear combination $ap + bq$ of them. So pick three quadratic polynomials appropriately for your replacing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's use $$f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
Then $$f''(0)=2a$$
Now we plug in this form of $f$ into the original equation, and we know that for quadratic polynomial is exact (so $\approx$ becomes $=$)
$$f''(0)=A\left(a(-h)^2+b(-h)+c)\right)+B(a0^2+b0+c)+C(ah^2+bh+c)$$
Now let's group terms as powers of $h$:
$$2a=h^2a(A+C)+hb(-A+C)+c(A+B+C)$$
This is valid for any value of $h$, and any values of $a,b,c$. So $$A+B+C=0\\-A+C=0\\(A+C)h^2=2$$
This means $A=C$ (in the second equation), $$2Ah^2=2\\A=\frac{1}{h^2}$$
Then finally $B=-2A$. With these:
$$f''(0)=\frac{f(-h)-2f(0)+f(h)}{h^2}$$
This is the same formula as on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences), with $x=0$.